# A link to a link in C++11 foreach loop

Tags: c++, qt

Assume I have the following code (C++/Qt):

```
QHash<QString, AppInfo*> links;
QList<AppInfo> apps = m_apps.values();
for (const AppInfo &app : apps) {
    // Doing something with #app variable...
    links.insert(app.other._appFile, &app);
}
```

`m_apps` is `QHash<QString, AppInfo>`, and `app.other._appFile` is a full path to a file.

Here goes the question: is the construction `&app` in the penultimate line correct? I need to have a non-constant pointer to AppInfo object to modify it later. Does `&app` link to a `const AppInfo&` or to `AppInfo` object directly? Won't app crash if I'll try to modify obtained `AppInfo*` object? Thank you.

*Sorry, English isn't my native language and I can't formulate the question title perfectly. Please do it instead of me.*

Comment: If you need a non-const `AppInfo*`, then the code you are showing should not compile. Does it compile?

Comment: Doesn't simply dropping the const in `const AppInfo &app : apps` work?

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't have a C++ compiler on hand right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`links` is `QHash<QString, AppInfo*>`, not `QHash<QString, const AppInfo*>`, therefore by

```
links.insert(app.other._appFile, &app);
```

you are initiating an implicit conversion from `const AppInfo*` to `AppInfo*`  which will result in a compiler error, rather than a runtime error (crash). An obvious solution is to traverse the map without const

```
for (AppInfo &app : apps) 
{

}
```